# How to get the length of a struct in Obj-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
int realLen = *((int*)((char*)sData.pData + 2));
NSLog(@"realLen = %d", realLen);
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:sData.pData length:realLen freeWhenDone:NO];
```

`sData` is a `struct` type and `pData` is a `void*` type in its property;

How can it get the correct length?

Comment: No,it's a question for me.

Comment: This is objective-C so please use that tag not C.

Comment: I'am sorry. But it's a problem about C on first line. OK,it's Obj-C.

Comment: The length is part of the message.

Comment: I think seems to be an alignment restrict rule violation.

Comment: @user3386109, You means that's right to get the length by this way?There's something I don't understand about C.

Comment: @user3386109, what message?

Comment: @WengCanzi, edit your question to show the declaration of the sData struct.

Comment: @DuncanC The message that `pData` points to.

Comment: @user3386109, how do you know anything about the data pData points to? The OP hasn't told us.

Comment: @DuncanC Exactly, so one has to wonder how you were able to answer a question that lacks even the most rudimentary details. You made your guess, I made mine.

Comment: I asked the op if he wanted to copy a pointer address, and provided code to get the size of the pointer, but that probably isn't what he wants.

Comment: My guess is that the size is in the sData struct.

Comment: I want to get the length of the char， exactly the string，and transfer to NSData

Comment: The earlier title of this did not provide much information, so I have guessed at a better one. Please improve it further if necessary. Note that "Please help me with Objective C" is not very indicative of the problem, so please avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to store the **address** stored in sData.pData in an `NSData` object? That is odd, and probably not proper memory management.

If that **is** what you want to do, you can use this:

```
int realLen = sizeof(sData.pData)
```

However, if what you want to do is to copy the data that sData.pData points to into your NSDats, you're out of luck. A C style `void*` does not let you tell the size of the thing it's pointing to. You have to know the size of the data.